# GDC in fedora binary release

Tags: d

I search for GDC binary release (D2 -> D1 is on source forge) for fedora, but it isn't exists. Then I want to compile it from source code, but I don't know how to do it. There isn't any configure or make file in root directory. Are there any good soul who helps me with it? And yes, I found question D programming on fedora 16 but it isn't response to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you, I am working on GDC RPM, and I will soon announce it (once I test it) on the http://forum.dlang.org/group/digitalmars.D.announce newsgroup. At the moment I am testing the ARM build on my ODROID-U2 box. I will soon push the SPEC and the rest to a Git repository at https://gitorious.org/rpm-gdc . The RPM installs GDC into `/opt/gdc` .

Speaking about GDC, I also have a patched gcc.spec which can be used to re-build system's gcc with enabled support for the D programming language. I have never submitted it to Fedora people as I expect GDC to be in GCC soon...

Meanwhile, you may want to get DMD RPM from http://dlang.org (or build Fedora RPMs using my DMD SPEC from https://gitorious.org/dejan-fedora ) or LDC, which should already be in the Fedora repository. If not, grab it from http://koji.fedoraproject.org.

Comment: Great, it's good to see that will be GDC RPM. And, how doesn't look with GDC in GCC? It will be soon or not? I can't use DMD because I need -nostdlib switch to disable implicit druntime.

Comment: -nostdlib isn't about druntime, that's about the C runtime. To disable druntime, use -defaultlib= and -debuglib= (=the name you want, by leaving it blank it shows you want none).

Comment: @DejanLekic What is the status of the RPM?

Comment: I just came back from a winter holiday... GDC RPM will be there soon. :)